# Find zero after peak

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm working with data sets that increase until they hit a peak and then quickly drop to zero; I want to find the location of that first zero after the peak as that will give me the failure time. However, the values leading up to the peak sometimes contain zero, and my current formula is returning the times for those. An example value set would be either something like [1;1;2;6;7;10;9;0;0;0] or something like [-1;-1;0;4;7;11;10;0;0;0].

We'll say the Time column is A and the Values column is B. I've calculated the minimum value after the peak with:

```
=MIN(OFFSET(B1,MATCH(MAX(B2:B4001),B:B,0),0,(4001-MATCH(MAX(B2:B4001),B:B,0))))
```

Using that as a helper cell, I'm retrieving the time at which this value occurs with:

```
=IF(*min_after_peak*>0,"PASS",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(*min_after_peak*,B:B,0)))
```

Side note - the "peak" lasts for more than one time measurement and can fluctuate slightly, so if the minimum after the peak is positive that means the sample didn't fail. The minimum after the peak is always either positive or zero (pass or fail, respectively).

Problem is, I don't know how to get MATCH to look at only values after the peak, or if that's even the right way to go.

Any thoughts on how to get the time corresponding to the first zero after the peak?

Comment: So in the first example, you're looking for the first 0 after the 9? And in the second example, you want the first 0 after the 10? What would you like returned, the position (e.g., 8 and 8, respectively)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in paired columns (starting in A1) please try:

```
 =INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(0,INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+65)&MATCH(MAX(B1:B10),B1:B10,0)&":"&CHAR(COLUMN()+65)&"10"),0)+MATCH(MAX(B1:B10),B1:B10,0)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a spreadsheet with your first set of data.

```
0   ispeak  peakExists  peakAndZero
1   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
1   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
2   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
6   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
7   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
10  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
9   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
0   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
0   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
0   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
```

I added a 0 in a1 and headers in B1, C1, and D1.

In the first row of the isPeak column, that is B2, I added `=IF(AND(A2>A1,A2>0),TRUE,FALSE)`. This puts a true in the cell if the value to the left (A2) is greater than the previous (A1) AND it is greater than 0.

In the first row of the peakExists column, that is C2, I added `=OR($B$2:B2)`. This puts a true in the cell if any of the previous from b2 (absolute) to my row has even a single true.

In the first row of the peakAndZero column, that is D2, I added `=AND(C2,A2=0)`. This puts a true in the cell if a peak exists and the value is a 0.

It looks like you know how to create the index of the row and you know how to select the lowest one with a true in peakAndZero, so I will leave this as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with an adaption to my original formula that avoids helper columns (I have several hundred data sets for this project). Used OFFSET to set an after-peak range in MATCH:

```
=IF(min_after_peak>0,"PASS",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B2:B4001),B:B,0)+MATCH(min_after_peak,OFFSET(B1,MATCH(MAX(B2:B4001),B:B,0),0,(3603-MATCH(MAX(B2:B4001),B:B,0))),0)))
```

To make it slightly easier to read:

```
=IF(min_after_peak>0,"PASS",INDEX(A:A,peak_row+MATCH(min_after_peak,OFFSET(B1,peak_row,0,(4001-peak_row)),0)))
```

where

```
peak_row = MATCH(MAX(B2:B4001),B:B,0)
```